# How to disable/ enable SSL protocol from chrome/ firefox browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl

I would like to know how to disable to SSL protocol from Chrome/ Firefox browser. I tried to disable SSL from chrome browser by doing [Settings] -> [Change Proxy Settings] -> [Advanced]. 
My Server is designed to accept only TLS protocols. It works well with IE11 browser. But coming to Firefox/ Chrome, I am unable to determine whether SSL is working or not.

I followed this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/mE-KUuYBkSU) to set for Chrome, but there is no hope. Does the SSL/TLS enabling/ disabling work in Chrome/ Firefox ?

Thanks,
RK

Comment: Chrome and Firefox don't implement SSL 2.0 and both have also disabled SSL 3.0 for about a year by default. For more configuration see https://www.ssl.com/how-to/turn-off-ssl-3-0-and-tls-1-0-in-your-browser/

Comment: Can we enable SSL3.0 in both browsers for testing purposes ? Want to ensure my server TLS connections are not open to browser when open with SSL3.0.

Comment: SSL/TLS handshake will use the best protocol, not the worst. Thus it does not help in testing if you enable SSL 3.0 (and better) at the client if the server can do better then SSL 3.0. To check your server I recommend to use [SSLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) instead.

Comment: It is a private domain. I can't test in SSLLabs.

Comment: Then use tools like [SSLyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze)